# Android Studio Adapter Not Working RecyclerView show nothing

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am a beginner developer for Android. And I have a problem. I have 2 lists. One for database list, one for API data. I send these lists to the recyclerView and do some operations. But
When sending to RecyclerView I guess API data list goes blank to RecyclerView. RecyclerView is not working. Please help me

RecyclerView Connection Method

```
private void HisseRecyclerBagla(View rootview){
    hisse_rc=rootview.findViewById(R.id.cuzdan_recycler_view_hisse);
    mdata =new ArrayList<>();

cuzdanModelHisse= new CuzdanDaoHisse().Cuzdan(vt2);


adapterHisse= new VarliklarımHisseAdapter(getActivity(),cuzdanModelHisse, mdata);
System.out.println("Api hisse size "+mdata.size());
hisse_rc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

hisse_rc.setAdapter(adapterHisse);

}
```

API Connection Method

```
   public void DovizList(String company){

        mdata =new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<cuzdanModelHisse.size();i++){


          Call<HisseModel> call = api2.getUsers("https://api.twelvedata.com/quote?symbol="
                +cuzdanModelHisse.get(i).getHisse_adi()+
                "&apikey=6b957670874e4a7f81e0c77b7f193395&source=docs");

            call.enqueue(new Callback<HisseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HisseModel> call, Response<HisseModel> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    HisseModel list = response.body();

                    hisse=list;
                    mdata.add(hisse);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else{
                    System.out.println("Hata");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HisseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

VarliklarimHisseAdapter

```
   package com.kdb2018.sasa.percent.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.kdb2018.sasa.percent.R;
import com.kdb2018.sasa.percent.model.CuzdanModel;
import com.kdb2018.sasa.percent.model.HisseModel;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class VarliklarımHisseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VarliklarımHisseAdapter.CardTasarimTutucu> implements Serializable {


    private Context context;
    private List<CuzdanModel.CuzdanModelHisse> cuzdanList;
    private List<HisseModel> mdata;


    public VarliklarımHisseAdapter(Context context, List<CuzdanModel.CuzdanModelHisse> cuzdanList, List<HisseModel> mdata) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cuzdanList = cuzdanList;
        this.mdata = mdata;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardTasarimTutucu onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cuzdan_rc_tasarim_hisse,parent,false);
        return new CardTasarimTutucu(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardTasarimTutucu holder, int position) {

                CuzdanModel.CuzdanModelHisse cuzdan = cuzdanList.get(position);

                for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
                    if(mdata.get(i).getSymbol().equals(cuzdan.getHisse_adi())){

                        holder.textViewHisseAdi.setText(cuzdan.getHisse_adi());
                        holder.textViewHisseDegeriAdapter.setText(mdata.get(i).getClose());
                        holder.textViewHisseAlisFiyatiAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(cuzdan.getHisse_alis_fiyati()));
                        holder.textViewHisseAdediAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(cuzdan.getHisse_alis_adeti()));

                    }
                }

    }

    public void setMdata(List<HisseModel> mdata) {
        this.mdata = mdata;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
 
        return Math.min(cuzdanList.size(),mdata.size());
    }

    public class CardTasarimTutucu extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        private TextView textViewHisseAdi, textViewHisseDegisimAdapter,
                textViewHisseAdediAdapter, textViewHisseDegeriAdapter, textViewHisseAlisFiyatiAdapter;
        public CardTasarimTutucu(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewHisseAdi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHisseAdiAdapter);
            textViewHisseDegisimAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHisseDegisimAdapter);
            textViewHisseAdediAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHisseAdediAdapter);
            textViewHisseDegeriAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHisseDegeriAdapter);
            textViewHisseAlisFiyatiAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHisseAlisFiyatiAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a cache problem. Try restarting or re-initializing your App or clear the caches